# Manifest merger failed versionCode is also present at

Tags: android, gradle

I have a complex `AndroidManifest.xml`, which contains a `receiver`:

```
<receiver android:name=com.my.package.ApplicationBroadcastReceiver>
```

I want to create an `AndroidManifest.xml` for the debug version of my app.
I placed that under `debug/AndroidManifest.xml`. The only difference in the debug manifest is that I am using another receiver:

```
<receiver android:name=com.my.package.DebugApplicationBroadcastReceiver>
```

For now, I copied `AndroidManifest.xml` into `debug/AndroidManifest.xml` and just changed that line. After reading [this page about merge rules](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge#merge_rule_markers), I specified this rule at the top of my `debug/AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.my.package"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0"
    tools:node="replace">
```

However, when building I am getting this error:

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute manifest@versionCode value=(1) from AndroidManifest.xml:5
is also present at AndroidManifest.xml:5
Attributes of <manifest> elements are not merged.
```

So even though I specified `tools:node="replace"` in the `manifest` tag, merging still fails.

My question has two parts:

A.How can I make the merging work?

B.Since the difference between `AndroidManifest.xml` and `debug/AndroidManifest.xml` is just one line, how can I just specify the line that is overriden instead of copying the whole file?

Comment: merging detail in done in gradle, you have to specify src, res etc in gradle so it can merge you manifest

Comment: you can also use [productflavor](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#build-types) for more specific result like... release flavor, debug flovor

Comment: try this : tools:node="merge"

Comment: @DharaJani I tried adding this to the `manifest` tag of `debug/AndroidManifest.xml` but the error persists. Should I add it in `AndroidManifest.xml` as well?

Comment: @octavian yes please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your error message, you need something like this:

```
tools:replace="android:versionCode"
```